# discord.net ban having a value of null

Tags: visual-studio, discord, discord.net

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(SocketUserMessage input, string[] parameters)
{
    if (parameters.Length == 0)
    {
        parameters[0] = "Unspecified";
        return;
    }
    var allBans = await Context.Guild.GetBansAsync();
    bool isBanned = allBans.Select(b => b.User).Where(u => u.Username == Context.User.Username).Any();

    if (!isBanned)
    {
        var targetHighest = (Context.User as SocketGuildUser).Hierarchy;
        var senderHighest = (Context.User as SocketGuildUser).Hierarchy;

        if (targetHighest < senderHighest)
        {
            await Context.Guild.AddBanAsync(Context.User);
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"**{Context.User.Username}** has been banned by Moderator {Context.User}. Reason: **{parameters}**");

            var dmChannel = await Context.User.GetOrCreateDMChannelAsync();
            await dmChannel.SendMessageAsync($"You have been banned from **{Context.Guild.Name}** by Moderator **{Context.User}** for **{parameters}**");
        }
    }
}
```

So i'm trying to make a command for banning people, but allBans keep getting a value of null. I'm not sure if i have written anything wrong or if it's an actual error..

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please describe your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Guild.GetBansAsync()` returns a list of user who are banned on this server, not the list of users that the caller wants to ban.

Instead, you should get the list of mentions from the caller's message.
You can do `Context.Message.MentionedUser` to get the list of mentioned user or
`Context.Message.MentionedUserIds` to get the list of IDs of the mentioned users.

Finally, you can do `await Guild.AddBanAsync(id/user)`.
(Docs for banning [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IGuild.html#Discord_IGuild_AddBanAsync_System_UInt64_System_Int32_System_String_Discord_RequestOptions_), there are a few optional arguments that you can pass in.)